# How do I formulate my for-loop code to insert values in specific html table cells?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I am having issues inserting values from an object into a dynamically generated HTML table.

Find below my simple HTML code:

```
<table id="table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am dynamically populating the table above using values from an object. The object is generated from saved values in the `localStorage`.

Find inline my javascript code along with my comments and explanation:

```
var array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactionData'));
console.log(array);
```

The `console.log(array)` as seem above, correctly yields:

[image: Results of the console.log code]

```
table = document.getElementById("table");

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
  console.log("Number of transactions: " +array.length);
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

  var x;
    for (x in array) 
    {
      var cell = newRow.insertCell(x);
      cell.innerHTML += array[x].payersNumber;

   }
}
```

My main issue seems to be within the scope of the *second* for-loop.
I'd like for the code here to populate every row in the table with (in this order) the **Number, Amount** then finally the **Status**.

The code in the second for-loop above erroneously fills in every cell in the table with phone numbers, and also adds additional columns as seen in the image below

[image: image of the erroneously generated dynamic table]

Kindly help me understand how I can correctly formulate my code to populate every row with the  **Number, Amount** and the **Status** values from the object.

Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected the problem lies here:

```
    for (x in array) 
    {
      var cell = newRow.insertCell(x);
      cell.innerHTML += array[x].payersNumber;

   }
```

According to the structure of your array each element is an object with six keys - your table just has three rows though - so it adds two additional cells which get populated from a non-existing entry in the object which makes it **undefined**.

I'd recommend adding the keys you want to be displayed inside the table in an array like (reflecting the order of your table):

```
var keys=["payersNumber","amount","paymentStatus"];
```

This way you can iterate over the keys inside the for-loop and populate the correct cells.

Here's an example:

```js
var array = [{
  amount: 12,
  payersNumber: 1245,
  paymentStatus: "okay"
}, {
  amount: 24,
  payersNumber: 3345,
  paymentStatus: "okay"
}, {
  amount: 45,
  payersNumber: 4534,
  paymentStatus: "not okay"
}];

table = document.getElementById("table");

var currentTransaction;
var keys = ["payersNumber", "amount", "paymentStatus"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log("Number of transactions: " + array.length);
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

  currentTransaction = array[i];
  for (var b = 0; b < keys.length; b++) {
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(b);
    cell.innerText = currentTransaction[keys[b]];
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I hope you can help out with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322097/how-do-i-insert-certain-values-of-an-array-as-a-css-style-property-for-a-td-in

Answer (score 1):

for(x in array), you are accessing the array, not the objects inside the array.

Try something like:

```
  var table = document.getElementById("table");

  console.log("Number of transactions: " + array.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
    var currentTransactionLength = Object.keys(array[i]).length;
    var currentTransactionObject = array[i];

    for (var x = 0; x < currentTransactionLength; x++) {
      var cell = newRow.insertCell(x);
      cellContents = currentTransactionObject[Object.keys(currentTransactionObject)[x]];
      cell.innerHTML += cellContents;
    }
  }
```

This way you are accessing the array on the first loop and then each object of that array on the second loop.

Comment: Thanks! your solution works, however not sorted according to the <th> headers: Number, Amount and status. Is there any way to sort & filter the objects in the second loop?