# How do I insert certain values of an array as a CSS style property for a <td> in a dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, css-tables

I have a script that collects data from an array and uses these to generate a dynamic table. Some of these values in the array are **Font Awesome** styles.

My existing script inserts all the values in the array into each table cell.
The intention is for the **Font Awesome** style values to be inserted as a cell style, during the rendering of the table.

In the code below, notice that the array properties for **paymentStatus** stores a CSS **Font Awesome** style value.

```
var array = [{
  amount: 12,
  payersNumber: 1245,
  paymentStatus: class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"
}];

table = document.getElementById("table");

var currentTransaction;
var keys = ["payersNumber", "amount", "paymentStatus"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log("Number of transactions: " + array.length);
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

  currentTransaction = array[i];
  for (var b = 0; b < keys.length; b++) {
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(b);
    cell.innerText = currentTransaction[keys[b]];
  }
}
```

How do I get the **paymentStatus** values to get inserted into the table as the style for each `<th>Status</th>` column?

Find below the HTML table that my existing code geneates:

```
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<tr>
  <td> 12 </td>
  <td> 1245 </td>
  <td> class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" </td>
</tr>
```

For the **Font Awesome** style to successfully be put in effect, it needs to be inserted into the `<td> </td>` as a class style. 
The desired effect would, therefore, look like this:

```
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>1245</td>
    <td class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the nested for-loop you can make a distinction based on the current value of **keys[b]**. If it's **paymentStatus** add an `<i>` tag with the css for the font awesome exclamation mark and use the **.innerHTML** property of the cell. If it's something else just assign the appropriate text to the **.innerText** proeprty.

```js
var array = [{
  amount: 12,
  payersNumber: 1245,
  paymentStatus: "okay"
}, {
  amount: 24,
  payersNumber: 3345,
  paymentStatus: "okay"
}, {
  amount: 45,
  payersNumber: 4534,
  paymentStatus: "not okay"
}];

table = document.getElementById("table");

var currentTransaction;
var keys = ["payersNumber", "amount", "paymentStatus"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

  currentTransaction = array[i];
  for (var b = 0; b < keys.length; b++) {
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(b);
    if (keys[b] == "paymentStatus") {
      cell.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle'></i>" + currentTransaction[keys[b]];
    } else {
      cell.innerText = currentTransaction[keys[b]];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/v4-shims.css">

  <table id="table" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Kindly see if you can also help me out with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338797/how-do-i-turn-a-table-cell-td-into-a-clickable-link-that-displays-hidden-colum

Answer (score 1):

You can use `classList.add` method to add `css` class to HTML element as follows:

```
for (var b = 0; b < keys.length; b++) {
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(b);
    if (keys[b] == 'paymentStatus') {
        let className = '';
        // it is assumed that paymentStatus value format is consistent
        const classNameArr = currentTransaction[keys[b]].split('=');
        if (classNameArr.length === 2) {
            className = classNameArr[1];
            cell.classList.add(className);
        }
    } else {
        cell.innerText = currentTransaction[keys[b]];
    }    
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful comment/solution. Kindly see if you can help me out with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338797/how-do-i-turn-a-table-cell-td-into-a-clickable-link-that-displays-hidden-colum