# How do I turn a table cell <td> into a clickable link that displays hidden column contents?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I have a script that generates a dynamic table from values stored in an array.

Though the array has **seven** properties (**equivalent to seven columns**), the dynamic table is designed to display only **three columns** out of **seven possible columns**. The reason for displaying only **three columns** out of seven, is due to layout design limitations.

What I would like to do to resolve this issue, is to make **one** cell in the table a clickable link `<a href="#"></a>`, that opens a popup **bootstrap card** that displays a detailed content (with the values from the all the seven properties) of that particular row.

Find below my script which shows the array configuration and the dynamic table script:

```
var array = [{
   TransactionTime: "August 2, 2019 4:34 PM"
   amount: "100"
   payersNumber: "0705357658"
   paymentStatus: "Success! payment received."
   statusIcon: "<i class='fas fa-check-circle colorBlue'></i> <a href='#'>"
   transactionNumber: "ATPid_40a31c1aad441a3de2f70a17669e651a"
   waitersName: "John.P"
},
{
   TransactionTime: "August 1, 2019 2:34 AM"
   amount: "150"
   payersNumber: "0705357658"
   paymentStatus: "Failed! payment not received."
   statusIcon: "<i class='fas fa-check-circle colorRed'></i> <a href='#'>"
   transactionNumber: "ATPid_40a31c1aad441a3de2f70a17669e651a"
   waitersName: "Maggie.A"
}];

table = document.getElementById("table");

var currentTransaction;
var keys = ["statusIcon", "amount", "TransactionTime"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log("Number of transactions: " + array.length);
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

  currentTransaction = array[i];
  for (var b = 0; b < keys.length; b++) {
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(b);
    cell.innerText = currentTransaction[keys[b]];
  }
}
```

Find below my HTML code:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/v4-shims.css">

  <table id="table" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

As you have probably noticed, all the **Status** cells/columns become links. How do I get each of these links to open up to Bootstrap cards that contain all the relevant row values specific each row?

Find below an example of what the generated table would look like:

[image]

Also, the HTML code demonstrating the structure of a table row:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to not use anchor tags and instead use JS event listeners.

You would need to assign a unique 'id' to each row in the column.

Add event listeners to either each row and screen for the user clicking the status button/image OR add event listeners to each status button/image and traverse the HTML tree to see which row the button belongs to.

Once you know the row that got called, you can then use JS to extract the information and package it up into an object for your bootstrap modal/card.

UPDATE:
You could do something like this,

```
// after you insert a new row you get the element node back...
var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
// assign a unique id value to it
newRow.id = 'something';

// add an event listener to the row
newRow.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // when someone clicks on the ROW, you get a hit, but you're not sure what part of the row they clicked on...
    //...so create a check to make sure they clicked on the button
    if (event.target === 'some_way_to_indicate_the_status_button') {
        let row_number = event.target.id;

        // use the row number to grab all data from that row
        // package all of that data into an object {} or array, whichever you choose, then do what you want with it
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTML displayed for one row of that image? Should look something like <tr><td>img</td><td>100</td><td>some_date</td></tr> I need to see how it gets structured.

Comment: Yes, of course, I have edited the original post by appending to it by adding an image to show the generated HTML structure. Kindly have a look.

Comment: I can't see it, but I'm assuming the <td>'s are wrappedin a <tr>. Attach an id, at the time of creation, to the <tr> tag. Also attach an event listener. The rest should be a piece of cake. This link should guide you from there, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp